# Change color of cursor in gvim

Tags: vim

I want to change the color of the cursor pending on the current mode.

Here is my code so far (*.gvimrc*).

```
set gcr=n:blinkon0
set gcr=i:blinkon0
highlight Cursor guifg=white guibg=red
highlight iCursor guifg=white guibg=green
```

Right now the cursor is gray, nothing changes.
Running `highlight Cursor guifg=white guibg=red` manually works, but not the line below.

I want the color green in *insert mode* and red in every other mode.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I got some help from the vim irc @ freenode.

Here is the solution.

```
au InsertLeave * hi Cursor guibg=red
au InsertEnter * hi Cursor guibg=green
```

Comment: With this I get the error `Error detected while processing InsertEnter Auto commands for "*": E254: Cannot allocate color green^M`

Comment: `autocmd ColorScheme * highlight Cursor guibg=green`

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work when leaving Insert Mode with ctrl-c/ctrl-[. It stays green.

Answer (score 2):

You have to actually specify the highlight group in the `gcr` setting. You also need to put them together, your second "i:" one overrides the first. It also overrides all your defaults, so even combining them doesn't cover the other modes, or the different shapes in modes like operator pending... check out the documentation. Try just altering the default to set your iCursor group on insert mode.

```
set gcr=n-v:block-Cursor/lCursor,c:block-iCursor/lCursor,ve:ver35-Cursor,o:hor50-Cursor,i-ci:ver25-iCursor/lCursor,r-cr:hor20-iCursor/lCursor,sm:block-Cursor-blinkwait175-blinkoff150-blinkon175
```

This is based on the defaults, except i, ci, r, cr, and c (insert, replace, and command line) all use your `iCursor` group.