# Change VIM cursor running on Console2

Tags: vim, console2

I can't change the type of the VIM cursor when I enter the Insert Mode, when I'm using Console2.

I wanted it to do just like in cmd, as shown in the Figure:

[image]

I tried do something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158860/change-color-of-cursor-in-vim), but It didn't work either.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe terminal vim can control the cursor. This is normally done by the terminal emulator (in this case Console2).

Comment: @FDinoff , I don't understand terminal emulators too much. I didn't 
understand why, calling VIM in cmd/dos, it WORKED, and calling VIM in Console2 it didn't work... I don't know the difference between the two cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ConsoleZ (https://github.com/cbucher/console) and select the cursor named "Console".

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it and have the same behaviour. It seems to be a bug in Console2. I would suggest [mintty](https://code.google.com/p/mintty/) or a preview build of [ConEmu](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/), I know from experience that both handle this correctly.